# How will law be enforced if violence becomes impossible?

Tags: government, earth, law, police

Yesterday, the alien wizard Handwavius flew by our planet. He saw how violent we were and decided to put a stop to it. He cast a spell on all humans to make us stop us being violent, then flew away again, thinking his mission was done. Now we have to live with the consequences.

From now on whenever a human decides to commit a violent act, they can't bring themselves to do it. They can imagine doing the act just fine, but not actually perform it. This is a mental block, not a muscle one. It will also apply to new humans.

Violence here is defined as "causing physical harm to other humans", and however the individual human interprets that. If you think, on some level, that your action will harm someone - then you can't do it. This doesn't apply to psychological harm, harsh words work just fine. Neither are you compelled to act to save someone in danger, you can only be forced to nonaction.

The block also apply to chains of actions. You can build a robot with a gun, but you can't program it to shoot people. Neither can you order someone to program a robot to shoots people, and so on - if violence is the intended end result, the action is prohibited.

The only way to cause violence is to literally not understand that your acts could cause harm to someone. Violence can therefore still be caused by young children, some severely mentally handicapped people, and indirectly by people not realizing the consequences of their actions. Nonhumans aren't covered, including animals and eventual AIs.

How will law enforcement work when things settle down a bit?  Can you stop or punish those committing certain crimes, and if so, how? Will new crimes or punishments be added to the law books to compensate, or old ones removed? Assume most current governments manage to stay in power.

**Edit** to clarify some things:
You can be compelled to nonaction, but not to action. This means that if you're unsure, or you think any action will lead to harm, you will do nothing. If you think an action will do small harm and inaction will do greater harm you will do nothing. 
Also, a psychopath that has no empathy will still not be able to hurt people. You would have to be damaged enough to not understand what violence even really is to be able to cause it.

---

This is an attempt to narrow down a too-broad question that I posted earlier and then deleted. If popular, I might have follow-up questions about other aspects later.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96045/discussion-on-question-by-grollo-how-will-law-be-enforced-if-violence-becomes-im).

Comment: I guess what is stumping everyone is the definition of "harm".  Would a surgeon be able to cut out cancer?  Would a tech be able to insert an IV?  Put Chemo into that IV?  Could anyone set a broken bone?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple: define ‘harm’ appropriately for the situation.

Clearly a person committing crimes is mentally ill and requires help. To leave them out in the open would be to cause them harm. Therefore the course of less ‘harm’ is to wrap them in a giant futon (Japanese police do this) and wheel them off to a nice safe prison cell.

Or, if they are threatening harm to others, by inaction a police officer will cause harm to another person. If they believe they can cause less harm to the criminal than the criminal will inflict then not only are they able to apprehend or even kill the criminal, *they must do so*

So just train your officers to have a slightly skewed definition of harm and you’re golden.

Oh, the same trick can work for anyone. Psychopaths who see no wrong in their actions are, under your rules, free to do whatever they like. After all, I was only stabbing the police officer so he’d stop trying to arrest me. Clearly arrest is more harmful to me than stabbing is to him.

Good luck!

Comment: Yup I didn't feel I had quite enough for an answer but this is the shape of it the situation described hasn't made violence impossible at all, just skewed things very slightly. Actually this may make police **more** violent than they are today not less since you _must_ mess with their concept of harm so they can do their job.

Comment: Bit of a nitpick: you don't just have to think that an action is *less harmful* than another action to take it, you have to think it is harm*less*. If choosing between two actions and both cause harm you default to inaction. You also can't be compelled to action, only to inaction. Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: @Grollo in law enforcement you do have to think of items as *less harmful* over *harmless*. For example, we call tazers and other weapons "less than lethal" not "non-lethal" because there is always that chance. Therefore: Joe's answer is fine and you just illustrated the mental warp that LE would have to do. If you have a person with the personality that is required for military or law enforcement work - one which seeks to protect - your options are not "do nothing and just watch a person cause harm" or "pick a harmless option" they are: "watch until you go crazy and cause harm to stop harm"

Comment: @JGreenwell In real life that is true. Not in this scenario. No matter how angry or upset you get, even if the person causing harm is a total psycopath, you can't take and action you think would cause harm. Not if you want to with all your being, not if it's justified, not if it causes less harm overall. If you would harm someone with your action, you can't do it. That's the whole point.

Comment: @Grollo the point is either I can justify it in my mind ("there just scum anyway, I'm just taking out the trash") or I'll gain a mental condition (due to the stress of that duality) and now I just bypass the "magic mental block"...and probably become way more dangerous. Or, put another way, mental blocks don't work. People can justify anything. Read a bunch of case law and history - people have *chilling reasoning for horrible actions all the time*

Comment: @Grollo Humans aren't rational. They are rationalizing. The "funniest" modern day example is the rationalization hamster. In this question, it will lead to dark places. If you can't "hurt humans", one of the two block will be explained away by our minds to make it happen.

Comment: @Grollo: That’s mostly semantics. I can justify killing a killer as preventing harm rather than causing it just fine. Sure: the killer dies, but overall I have prevented harm from occurring. Same with warfare: I’m not killing one person, I’m preventing that person from harming his country by resisting the Glorious Path of Freedom. If you look at it with the right (twisted) logic in place anything is possible. The only limit is just how warped your brain can be.

Answer (score 6):

**This will be dark!**

Psychopaths will reign free. The police, mostly consisting of normal people can't really do much. On the other hand, rapist aren't harming the other, they were just too shy to say they wanted it.

The only way, bribe the borderline psychos with material goods to take out the truly trashy and unmanageable ones.

Maybe use hypnosis, mental manipulation, drugs to create enforcers who don't think. But even this would be prohibited as it creates future harm. Hell, hiring psychos wouldn't work as it creates harm in the long run.

You may want to check out **Psycho-Pass**... not exactly the same, but quite close to what you are describing. That series still gives me nightmares.

Comment: Psychopaths know that they're commiting violence, they simply don't experience empathy or remorse.  As the OP described it, the mere knowledge that an act is violent should be enough to prevent it; no empathy required. Similarly, I believe most rapists know that they are causing harm and use the "I know (s)he secretly wanted it" defense disingenuously after the fact.  Either way, arresting them should still be easy; even the most impaired mind can see that punching a police officer who is only doing their job is a violent act.  A few cops gently taking them by the arm should be all it takes.

Comment: @IAntoniazzi I don't think so. Without empathy it is easy to convince yourself that a) they aren't truly hurting b) they aren't truly human. I'm pretty sure they aren't. You have no idea how messed up human minds can get. Police can't move anyone. The moment they try against someone who isn't willing, they would be hurting them.

Comment: I disagree that a lack of empathy removes the understanding of the violence.  I can swat a fly and I know that I've harmed that fly, I just don't care because it's a fly.  I have no empathy for the fly, but I still know that I've harmed it. OP defined violence as "causing physical harm to other humans."  Perhaps OP can clarify whether humanness depends on the perception of the perpetrator.

Comment: @IAntoniazzi The "fly" has a chronic disease and suffering through hell. It would kill itself, if could, I'm saving it from further suffering. I'm not hurting it, I'm releasing it from its mortal agony, by letting its soul fly free. Like I said... no idea how messed up humans can get.

Comment: are you saying that psychopaths believe all of their victims are suffering and that killing them is beneficial?  That may be true for a few select cases, but if you are claiming that the majority of psychopaths think this way, I would ask you to provide support for that statement.

Comment: @IAntoniazzi Nope, naturally not for all of them. But my point is, that similar level of delusion are not unheard of. They would gain free reign by their screwed up believes and others would be unable to stop them as that causes harm. Without becoming mentally ill themselves.

Comment: If someone was so delusional as to believe that all human beings are frustrated suicides, then any rational person would understand that arresting that person and seeing to it that they received psychiatric care would be beneficial, not harmful.  Once the imprisonment is framed as not-harmful, any non-violent means to achieve that end should be permissible.  Ten cops with riot shields surround the guy and corral him into a nice padded room without ever laying a hand on him. No harm done.

Comment: @IAntoniazzi I reference my [earlier comment](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/150483/how-will-law-be-enforced-if-violence-becomes-impossible?noredirect=1#comment472170_150483) for a small list of atrocities which show the ability of humans to see other humans as "not human". Also, the suspect would start fighting the officers (their just *sheep* or *bugs* in his way) causing himself harm by bashing against their shields and then they would have to back off (drunks do this when you just put them in the back of a squad car sometimes). Less-than-lethal is not the same as no harm

Comment: @JGreenwell I don't doubt the existence of people who disbelieve in the humanity of others.  I merely believe they are a tiny minority.  In the cases of the genocides you mentioned, I sincerely doubt that everyone along the chain of command and every foot soldier could be said to " fully believe [their victims] are not human, without any doubt." (This is OP's criteria)  Many in these cases are serving an authoritarian leader out of fear, loyalty, or power-lust; after all, the disloyal often end up on the wrong end of these things and self-preservation is a powerful motivator.

Comment: @IAntoniazzi Let's simplify it. I'm a narcissist. I'm unique and intelligent. All these annoying, imitating, soulless pests around me can't possibly be the same as me. They are soulless drones incapable of individual thought. I'm human. They aren't. I can't hurt myself, but can hurt them. I feel my own pain, don't feel theirs. This is just a simulation. They are NPC's restricted from hurting me, the true human. And you can doubt it, but I CAN believe in this.

Comment: Again, I don't doubt that such people exist.  I simply don't believe there are enough of them to have a serious impact on society

Comment: @IAntoniazzi *did they all believe it*? probably not. *Did many come to believe it through indoctrination*? You bet. *Is it worse with those which involved child soldiers (to whom violence becomes the absolute norm from an age when they don't have the capability to understand)*? Absolutely. The point is not that all of them thought this. The point is if a few (a tiny minority) did, they'd have nothing standing in their way (all good people can do is really just ask them to stop) and through indoctrination would eventually increase in number until they either ruled or chaos & violence ruled.

Comment: But how would that indoctrination happen?  You need enough true believers to create an entire propaganda campaign.  I don't think you could build that kind of movement without attracting the attention of the overwhelming majority who would work to stop you.

Comment: @IAntoniazzi If it is necessary for survival, for protection of self, I believe even you would start to think this way. Otherwise, you end up dead. On indoctrination, since those NOT indoctrinated can't harm them, their resistance is futile and laughable.

Comment: @IAntoniazzi the way it is happening in places like the Sudan, Omo Valley, Congo, Somalia, Columbia, and other locations (not even including racist groups or suicide bombers in this) **today**. Just now there would be nobody to stop those leaders at the top and, again, by the OPs own statement the children would bypass the mental block. It might take centuries but eventually just the groups we have now would spread

Comment: If this wizard came here today, I believe 75% of the people working in the regimes you mentioned would suddenly find themselves incapable of doing their jobs.  Many at the top are in it for power, not because they believe.  Many at the bottom are in it for fear, not because they believe.  Regimes like this can't exist without a lot of people who are "just following orders" and, in this world, they would be incapable of doing so.

Comment: @IAntoniazzi and as I've given enough of the evidence of my theories and adding any other evidence (the Jung analysis of serial killers and other violent dictators that I had to study) would still end in a difference of opinion (unless someone can read minds) its pointless to continue. If you have evidence of your opinions, I would simply suggest adding it to your answer (and that some of this discussion is added to this answer) to improve them and thank you for the interesting discussion. Despite my studies of this subject and the dark theories I've developed, I hope that you would be correct

Comment: @JGreenwell As evidence I would cite the Nuremberg trials, where many said they didn't believe the indoctrination, they were just following orders, and the accounts that I've heard from former child soldiers where they have talked about fearing for their lives if they didn't obey the group they were fighting for, despite not wanting to participate in violence.  I'm sorry, I'm not able to link to those right now.  But I agree that this is unknowable without such a wizard in existence.  Thank you, too, for a lively debate.

Answer (score 5):

Apprehending criminals shouldn't be a problem.  Since the criminals cannot harm the police, it should be enough to surround a criminal with police and gently guide them to a car.  So the real problem comes in enforcement, since most punishments clearly cause harm.

What comes to my mind is the apparatus that some jurisdictions currently have around lethal injection. I don't remember where I heard this, but I believe in some places, they have 3-5 people each pull a lever; one of those levers activates the infusion of the lethal injection, but the people pulling the levers have no idea which one is the real one.  Each one can choose to believe that they pulled one of the dummy levers.  The person who pulled the real lever, who actually killed the prisoner, is never aware of it.  Perhaps this idea could be adapted; several judges sit on a single court case, each hands down a sentence in secret, one is chosen at random and delivered to the guilty party without the judges knowing which was chosen.  The people carrying out the sentence, delivering the prisoner to jail or what have you, are not causing the harm, they are merely carrying out the wishes of the judge.  And each judge can hand down a sentence secure in the belief that it won't be chosen.

Comment: What happens when the criminal don't want to go? Any nudging may be interpreted as harm and prevented. The police will be useless. Thats after the fact rationalization. None would be able to pull the lever. None would be able to set up the system of levers as it would be clearly used for harm.

Comment: @Lupus the police don't move until the criminal does, they leave a path open for him as his only way to move.  It they get tired, they can switch out with other officers.  The officer the furthest down will have food and water.

Comment: @RichardU beat me to my answer re: police.  I agree that capital punishment in any form would be impossible in your world; I merely described that system as an example of one where the people causing harm do not know that they are causing harm.  The system of multiple judges might work, but if the mere knowledge that one *might* cause harm is enough to prevent an action then this is also impossible.  1/

Comment: The only way forward, that I can see, is to create a penal system that is actually beneficial to the criminal; provide drug and alcohol rehabilitation, anger-management counseling, education, job-training and anything else the criminal might need to redirect them towards lawfulness.  This way a judge could send a criminal to jail without harming them.  Incarceration would genuinely be for their own good.

Comment: @RichardU Preventing the criminal from drinking and eating also considered as harm. Also this only works if the criminal isn't a psycho and the restrictions are applied. Even then a lot of policeman are required, can't really see how that works. Antoni... and that rehabilitation is beneficial a good example of rationalization. Anything can be considered beneficial or harmful, depending on mindsets. A drug addict may suffer(harmed) by the withdrawal symptoms.

Comment: The criminal can eat and drink any time, he just has to walk into the jail cell first.  If he refuses to do so, then he his harming himself, the police are not culpable.  Yes, a lot of police would be required, but crime would also be extremely rare; the only crimes possible would be ones of negligence.  Theft, assault, murder, rape, and fraud would mostly be things of the past since only those with extreme mental illnesses would be able to commit those crimes.  Hell, the drug trade would probably collapse since so much violence is required to sustain it.

Comment: As far as rehabilitation: yes, the people working in the criminal justice system would have to firmly believe that the rehabilitation centers were beneficial.  If you didn't believe that, you would not be well suited to work as a prosecutor or a judge.  And it would behoove the government to make sure that these centers were effective and successful.  And yes, withdrawal can be harmful, which is why its best to undergo it under the supervision of a top-notch medical team.  To leave an addict out in the street, where they may have to undergo withdrawal on their own, would definitely be harmful.

Comment: I like your 2nd paragraph but with the first I wonder what if the suspect starts trying to pull away from the police, push against them, or otherwise move so as to cause harm to himself (they did this a lot in my experience, esp. if their is a mental condition, or drugs/alcohol involved). The police would just have to move so he had a clear path to *where the suspect wanted to go* otherwise they would cause that person harm by trying to direct him. Still works if intended self-harm is not allowed because person would likely not be trying to hurt himself just get away.

Comment: @IAntoniazzi By adding conditions to someone's well being, is a slippery slope you may not want to take. I imprison a woman to a flat, and unless she has sex with me, she won't get food or water. I'm not harming her, she harm herself, she just have to do as I say... see? If you think those would be the past, you are overly optimistic. If people realize there is no way to punish them, they will look for loopholes. Those who can rewrite themselves WILL be successful. Not moral, but the winners as everything is their to take... they will replace the population in a few generations.

Comment: @IAntoniazzi On Rehabilitation. You just agreed that people can believe in something with unclear and delayed outcome, to be able to force themselves to hurt others in the short term as they will see it as beneficial. If they can do this for good, sure as hell will do this for their gain. I rest my case.

Comment: @Lupus no conditions are added.  Food and water are available, all he has to do it get it.  Same as someone going to the refrigerator, unless you're suggesting that refrigerators are violence.

Comment: @RichardU See JGreenwell's comment about shield bashing, ... Your scenario may work, but outlines a bigger problem. You are preventing the criminal from taking any other source of substance other than those provided. If this is allowed... transport them to the middle of the desert. There is a water source in walking distance, but if they choose a wrong direction, they are dead...

Comment: OP's scenario says that you cannot take any action that would harm someone.  Standing still and holding a shield harms no one.  All the harm is being done by the subject, they are the person taking action.  OP has already said that you can only imprison someone if you intend to feed them and not harm them; so both stranding someone in the desert and raping your prisoner are not permissible.  If the rehabilitation centers are actually, provably beneficial, then no self-delusion is necessary for those in law enforcement to do their jobs.

Comment: @Lupus dropping someone off in the middle of a desert where they **could** find water isn't the same thing.  Holding food right in front of someone and them only having to go and take it is not the same as leaving them somewhere they might never find it.

Comment: @RichardU The way I see it. Restricting their options to sustain themselves can be considered harmful. What if they are paranoid/allergic and won't eat, drink the water, food provided? Forcefeeding could be harmful. We are back to, could surgeons cut the patients? Much depends on the exact nature of the restriction. It would be "fun" living and experimenting with this. As it remains a thought experiment, let's say you represent the optimist and me, the pessimist outcome.

Comment: @lupis  Fair enough assessment.  But it's the opposing views that make for good ideas :D  It could go even further than you suggest.  How about setting a bone?  That hurts like hell.  Killing cancer through Chemo.....  more often you end up killing the patient.

Comment: I was wondering about surgery too.  There are many things that cause a temporary harm in service of a long-term benefit.  Dental cleanings also come to mind.  Any kind of injection.  Even some forms of physical therapy certainly cause pain.  I think this world might have bigger problems than law enforcement

Comment: @RichardU Since misspelled my id, didn't get the notification. I second that. Criminals will be a big problem if some of them get free reign for a time, but people adapt. The more immidiate issue would be healthcare... and manufacturing? Could you operate a factory, oil drill, nuclear plant which outputs is slightly, but still harmful to humans?

Comment: @Lupus how about any physical training?  A coach couldn't even make his team run laps, could he?  When learning martial arts, we had to learn how to fall without injuring ourselves.  Guess what happened the first few times?  Wow, this goes pretty deep down the rabbit hole, doesn't it?

Comment: @RichardU Training isn't "harm", even if it is painful. Ok, done wrong, it is harmful, but that's self-harm and most people certainly not aware of it at first. Only by verbal abuse, like in military :D Yes, it does indeed.

Comment: @Lupus In order to train your body in martial arts class, you are being hit in the gut to learn how to take a punch, getting thrown to learn how to fall, have people throwing punches and kicks at you to learn to block.  Coaches will have athletes run laps as punishment, and you want to puke afterwards.  Some do... Now, as to Uncle Sam's Misguided Children... yeah, the USMC DI's are known for two things, how rough they are, and how protective they are of their fellow marines.

Comment: @RichardU I know. I thought you meant sport training coaches like football or so. Yeah, I know exactly what you mean! Valuable memories... But, well, that's not harm, that's love! And we are back to that humans would find workarounds to deal with the mental blocks. Those better at it would be more successfull as well as ruthless.

Answer (score 4):

This reminds me of the methods used in the book *World War Z*: there, due to lack of resources to police the jails, people who broke the law were put in stocks or otherwise publicly punished. These punishments, instead of being about violence, were intended to shame the criminal into compliance. More importantly, they also persuaded the rest of the population not to break the laws; public humiliation in small communities was a very harsh punishment.

This method could be used here, capitalizing on the leeway allowed for psychological harm. And then, for those people who didn’t care about public scorn, the non-violent prisons other answers go into detail about could be used to separate them from the rest of the population.

Comment: That's called "deterrence" punishment, there's a fierce debate about it as [a parenting tool](https://www.nbcsandiego.com/news/local/Mt-Woodson-Elementary-Student-Sign-Public-Punishment-Debate-243746201.html) and it has been used with ["shaming" cases recently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_v._Gementera) ... which are also debated (though not with stocks themselves as that is very much a corporal punishment which also carries a dark history involving the slave trade)

Answer (score 3):

If I interpret your wizard's spell as preventing humans from acting with violence towards one another then crime reduces to things like theft, vandalism, extortion and similar things that don't require violence or the threat of violence to carry out.

If law enforcement identified a suspect, then your own rules would make arrests pretty simple.  The cops couldn't use violence, but the suspects couldn't resist much more than running away or saying no.  So the police could use overwhelming numbers to box the suspects in and literally pick them up and carry them to jail-- since they are not intending violence this would be okay.  I imagine this would really mess cops heads since its not that they must show restraint but that they must not want to injure someone physically to do their jobs

I imagine incarceration would change.  I am visualizing prisoners riding around on Segways or automated carts that moving from their cells to courts to prisons.  This would deny them their capacity to not cooperate.

If on the other hand, I interpret the wizard's spell as preventing harm.  Then almost all crime also vanishes.  Certainly any deliberate acts.  You'd be left with manslaughter, speeding, and violations of city, state, and federal ordinances.  Most of these are dealt with fines.  And the rare cases when someone inadvertently kills someone with their car or their poorly designed airplane then the solution for the thought-experiment (above) would work.

Comment: "The cops could use violence" No? That is pretty much the point, they can't.

Comment: @Grollo That looks like a typo, based on the following sentences.

Answer (score 3):

This problem was actually at the root of the first of Asimov's 3 laws of robotics.

1. A robot may not injure a human being or, through inaction, allow a human being to come to harm.

This was intended, of course, for robots, but your wizard has a related effect on humans.  Asimov's robots were physically incapable of intentionally harming a human being.  Many, upon finding they accidentally harmed a human were driven into a sort of shock, unable to recover from the contradiction with the first law.

And, of course, Asimov didn't make a career out of how the 3 laws work.  He made a career out of showing how they don't work.  The Solarians in one of his works created a set of robots which had a warped definition of what "human" was, so that they interpreted the first law to only apply to Solarians.  Individuals not of Solarian descent were simply not considered to be human, so could be exterminated with impunity if so commanded.

Thus the first step to breakdown in this society is the development of a pathologically raised group of enforcers who are taught to not believe normal people are actually "human."  They are less than human.  Perhaps they are demons.  Indeed, it's well recognized that the first step to waging war in our world is to demonify the opposition so that you may commit violence against them without concern for its morality.

Now all that is required is to have the ruling class be able to issue commands to these enforcers knowing what they are capable of.  This is trivially done by setting it up such that the agent issuing the orders is not the *cause* of the violence.  Orders are issued such that, should the suspect merely comply, no violence occurs.  It is only the subjects own actions which cause harm to them.  Once again, there is prior art in fiction.  Frank Herbert's Dune has the Tleilaxu Face Dancers, brutal shapeshifting assassins.  As a ritualistic rule, they always ensure there is one way out of their trap, and that the subject *could* find the solution.  Of course, such a solution is typically not found, resulting in the death of the subject.

This is not just fiction, of course.  The concept of "proximate cause" is already in our legal system, assigning "fault" for an accident based on the last individual to be able to act to avoid the accident.  We tell our children "Well if you just ate dinner like you were supposed to..." or "Well if you just did your homework when you were supposed to..."  This way of thinking is not new, and its relatively easy to fall into.

One could also leverage the idea that inaction can cause harm as well.  This is at the heart of a recent abortion bill in the US which sought to require abortion doctors provide emergency care to failed partial birth abortion infants.  One argument is that this was a superflouous bill, as said doctor was already under oath to provide care to all living beings (and the infants in question were clearly already legally living).  However, on the other side, it points to the reality that inaction can cause the *death* of an individual.  In a less politically charged example, consider moving out of the way of an emergency vehicle.  Failure to act can cause harm by impeding motion.

Add to this any chaotic element, and we find that it's always *possible* that any action can cause harm, or inaction can cause harm.  Anyone who finds this out will be stuck between a paralyzing inability to act in a way that might cause harm and a anti-paralyzing inability to fail to act.

The particular solution to that puzzle from Chinese philosophy is called Wu Wei... or more completely wei wu wei.  Translated into English, its "action without action."  Making sense of that philosophy using Western thinking is notoriously difficult, and in Chinese thinking, countless theses have been penned on the topic (and arguably a few religions).  Needless to say, if everybody suddenly understood wu wei, we would find the structure of the world *dramatically* changes, and we have to rethink the meaning of things like "law enforcement."

Comment: and then of course the most famous perversion of the 3 laws of Robotics comes in the Foundation novels where it turns out one robot has reprogrammed itself to have a 0th law that overrides the first law, a law to protect humanity against itself that allows that robot to cause insufferable harm to billions as long as humanity as a whole is better off as a result (according to that robot's own definition of being better off).

Answer (score 3):

Effectively this has been played out many times over the centuries.

Religions often state something like "love your brother like yourself", "do no harm to other people", etc. etc..

People tend to then just redefine those they dislike as not being covered by those statements. If you redefine criminals as not being fully human, you're no longer restricted by your mental block on not harming humans.

This would of course lead to a system in which people are convicted first, THEN arrested, never being present at their trials and thus incapable of defending themselves. Which is of course exactly what happens and happened quite often in totalitarian countries already.

And such mental gymnastics are not uncommon of course. The Germans in the 1930s/40s defined Jews, Slavs, mental health patients, blacks, basically anyone not of Germanic descent as "Untermenschen", literally "underpeople" but more accurately translated as "subhuman" and did things to them that they'd never dream of doing to "real" human beings.

The same has happened in many places and eras all around the world.

Answer (score 2):

Criminal prosecution isn't really about harm anyway. So the death penalty goes away, but [statistics show](https://www.amnestyusa.org/a-clear-scientific-consensus-that-the-death-penalty-does-not-deter/) it isn't a [deterrent to](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/JLpaper.pdf) [future crimes](https://deathpenaltyinfo.org/policy-issues/deterrence), not really.

Jail, if managed properly, isn't directly harmful. Especially if the guards and other inmates are physically incapable of harming any inmates. And, over time, prison population should drop quite significantly as violent crime is done.

You also have fines -- at least, for those who have enough income that fines aren't a direct cause of harm.

Actually, this raises many interesting side questions: Would the spell consider repossessing a person's house as harm? What about denying access to medical care? Or enacting laws to reduce homeless people's access to public parks and park benches? I think how you define "harm" is going to seriously impact your world here.

Honestly, I think your world is going to have so many other problems that law enforcement is going to be the least of your worries. An entire industry just lost their jobs. What will the quite suddenly now-ex-military do? What will the weapons manufacturing industry do? You've just unemployed about [27 million military personnel](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/MS.MIL.TOTL.P1). Plus the military-industrial complex that supports them. The world spends about [US$1.82 trillion](https://www.defensenews.com/global/2019/04/28/heres-how-much-global-military-spending-rose-in-2018/) on military budgets. This doesn't count all the non-military weapons trading, etc. This will have some impact on the global economy. Is that harm?  ...Sorry, off topic...

Jail, in your post-harm society, won't be directly harmful, so it is still on the table for the drastically reduced population of new prison inmates. And that jail time will be safer and less harmful for inmates the world over.

Fines, at least for well-off individuals, will still work, too. And we might find less need for the fines, as at least some people will be less likely to do things like contaminate rivers that feed into water supplies or let [lead pipes poison entire cities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flint_water_crisis), perhaps. So the need for fines should drop, and fines will be used less against those who are least able to pay them, hopefully.

Comment: The death penalty is the only technique available to the criminal justice system that has been demonstrated to reduce recidivism by 100%

Comment: @EDL Added links to support that sentence, but basically, a death penalty doesn't statistically reduce violent crime in credible studies. Given that most violent crime is a crime of passion, that makes sense.

Comment: @EDL Only 99.9999%. There was that Jesus guy who was executed for preaching sedition, then came back and did it again.

Comment: @Mike Scott, LOL

Comment: @CaM as the convict is dead and can't commit other crimes, the fact that recidivism is 0 for those receiving capital punishment is inherent to the punishment.

Comment: The point is that studies show death penalty does not reduce crime overall, therefore it does not act as a deterrent for future crimes. I wasn't/didn't mention repeat crimes at all. I'm talking about OVERALL CRIME RATES do not improve with the introduction of death penalties, statistically speaking. ALSO: a pro/con debate about the death penalty is completely 100% off topic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering how much crime prevention / detection actually requires violence by the police? (Even before the wizard comes)

Now, all violent crime is eliminated.

Since the criminals can't commit acts of violence, there is no need for the police to use violence to defend themselves. A criminal's only choices are to come quietly or run away. The police just need to be able to run faster!

So the police now train themselves in techniques of non-violent restraint - i.e. a martial art that allows them to use physical force to restrain a criminal, without harming them, or using strategies to out-maneuver the criminals trying to escape. Since the criminals can't fight back, just try to non-violently resist the restraint, all it takes is for the police to be better trained in this technique than the criminals.

Jails are surely easier to manage - sure the guards can't use violence to control the convicts, but neither can they use violence to threaten the guards (or each other!)

Answer (score 0):

Religion has already been mentioned, so I'll go with another one: Coventry.  Criminals are regarded as beyond the pale of society.  No one will hire one, no one will deal with one, no one will sell to one, no one will associate with one, no one will *speak* to one.  They are treated as if they do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

A big chunk of the state has become unnecessary. What are soldiers and policemen to do? Protect people from tigers? There can't be that much demand for that. Many laws relate to preventing harm from getting done or compensating harm done. So courts will be a lot less busy.

This doesn't mean strong states can't be a thing. If he monopolizes enough essential supplies, like water and crops, a dictator that believes himself benevolent should still be able to get his way by not authorizing essential shipments of necessary goods to dissenters. He can protect his supplies by having people physically blocking access to his sources, because his enemies can't get those guards out of the way without there being a risk of them getting hurt. A lot of harm can be done through inaction.